# Validar check tildador y habilitar dos botones con Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Estimados estoy buscando la forma de que al tildar un check habilite dos botones de accesso.

La vista muestra la siguiente pantalla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Actualmente puedo tildar el check y habilita el botón **"ACCEDER"**, pero no sé como puedo habilitar también el botón de **"ACCEDER CON GOOGLE"** debido a que es un **HREF**.
Por default tendría que tener ambos botones deshabilitados.

La función que utilizo es la siguiente:

```
onchange="document.getElementById('aprobarBtn').disabled = !this.checked;"
```

Y el formulario completo con los botones:

```
<div class="text-center">
   <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox small">
      <input onchange="document.getElementById('aprobarBtn').disabled = !this.checked;" type="checkbox" 
      class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck">
      <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck">Acepto políticas de uso y privacidad</label>
   </div>
<div>

<button id="aprobarBtn" disabled type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-user btn-block">
   Acceder
</button>

<a href="{{ url('login/google') }}" class="btn btn-google btn-user btn-block">
   <i class="fab fa-google fa-fw"></i> Acceder con Google
</a>
```

**EDICIÓN**

Mi botón de Google quedó de la siguiente manera:

```
<a href="{{ url('login/google') }}" id="aprobarBtnGoogle" class="btn btn-google 
  btn-user btn-block disable">
  <i class="fab fa-google fa-fw"></i> Acceder con Google
</a>
```

Y mi función de Javascript:

```
function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById("aprobarBtn").disabled = !document.getElementById("aprobarBtn").disabled;
        document.getElementById("aprobarBtn").disabled ? document.getElementById("aprobarBtnGoogle").classList.add("disable"): document.getElementById("aprobarBtnGoogle").classList.remove("disable");
        }
```

El problema es que de esta manera no me activa el botón al hacer clic en el check. Que estaría faltando?

Gracias por destinar tiempo en mi pregunta. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

La etiqueta `<a>` no posee el atributo `enable`. Para "imitar" este comportamiento puedes hacerlo mediante una clase css de la siguiente forma:

```
.disable{
pointer-events: none;
}
```

Luego asigna esa clase de manera dinámica a tu ancla:

```
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("aprobarBtn").disabled = !document.getElementById("aprobarBtn").disabled; 
  document.getElementById("aprobarBtn").disabled ? document.getElementById("aprobarBtnGoogle").classList.add("disable"): document.getElementById("aprobarBtnGoogle").classList.remove("disable"); 
}
onChange="myFunction()"
```

Nota que la clase se asignará al ancla si el botón `aprobarBtn` esta habilitado(suponiendo que quieres que ambos se habiliten a la vez). Recuerda que puedes modificar otros aspectos mediante la regla css: como el color, el tamaño, etc.

Suerte.!

Comment: Hola gracias por tu respuesta. Al hacer clic sobre el checkbox no se habilita el pointer para hacer clic en el botón de Google. a mi botón le agregué el  id="aprobarBtnGoogle"  y la clase disable. Me falta algo?

Comment: Actualiza tu pregunta, y permíteme ver el estado actual de tu código

Comment: Agregué la edición, muchas gracias!!

Comment: Declaraste la función myFunction pero no la utilizas en ningún momento. Actualicé mi respuesta.

Comment: Hola @JoelMuñozMoran estoy buscando y tratando de entender que sucede que no me funciona, es claro lo que me indicas pero no me funciona. La consola no me marca ningún error. El botón no se activa.

Comment: Verificaste esto? onChange="myFunction()"

Comment: En el código que actualizaste no vi si hiciste ese cambio

Comment: Yo mismo probé el código y funciona sin ningún problema. Si el problema persiste tal vez debas usar algún sitio como codepen para revisar el problema a profundidad

Comment: Si agregué onChange voy a ver bien que pasa, entiendo que debería funcionar no sé si a lo mejor livewire me está bloqueando la funcionalidad, pero lo analizo bien y te comento, muchas gracias!!